# Ethernet MTU Fragmentation on a STM32

Tags: c, udp, stm32, ethernet, lwip

I'm using the **LWIP** library and the NUCLEO-F746ZG board. I’m trying to send a **2000 bytes** JSON string through Ethernet using **UDP** protocol, but as my packet exceeds the **Ethernet MTU** (1500 bytes) so my data is fragmented. I´ve used all kind of programs (SocketTest3, Hercules) to test If I could read the full JSON string, but nothing works. However, I can see the traffic generated by this packet using Wireshark:

This is the Fragmented IP protocol Packet:
[image: WireShark capture Fragmented Packet]

This is the UDP Packet, whic is the rest of the data:
[image]

I don’t know if I can avoid this fragmentation with the same packet length. Perhaps configuring some parameter of the LWIP library. I don’t know if there is any way to read this fragmented Data properly.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Receiving OS IP stack should be able to reassemble it and give it properly to the application. PuTTY is not a proper tester to check it since it is mainly an ssh client. Are you sure you are listening in *UDP* protocol and in the right port (1338 in the capture)? Are you *capturing* the packets with wireshark in the same machine that the server that is supposed to receive the packet (SocketTest or Hercules)?

Comment: Hi @eugenioperez, first of all, thanks for responding. You are right PuTTY is not the right program for testing that, I didn't use it in this case. I'm listening in the correct IP and port because when the packet is smaller than 1500 bytes I can read the message properly. Do you know any other programs I can use?

Comment: You're welcome :) This "solution" would go in the other direction, but if your network is completely private, could you try to increase MTU in sender machine and in LWIP stack? That would solve many problems at once and should be the preferred solution. If your goal is to support fragmented packets at any cost, you should check if lwip is configured to effectively defrag the IP packets, and that is able to receive >1500 bytes per UDP datagram and does not have a hard limit in rx packets.